# Assigning jobs to minimize cost - Linear programming

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I'm stuck trying to solve this linear programming question.

You want to make a website with a list of features F, which are n elements long. Each feature has a corresponding value for how long it'll take to implement it. Since you dont know how to program, you enlist the help of your m programmer friends. Each of your friends have three attributes
Preferences: (the list of features they like to program, this is a subset of F)
Hours : The amount of time they are willing to work
Cost: The amount of money they will charge per hour
Note that your friends will only charge you money if they work a feature thats not in their preferences.

To summarize
For i = 0 to n,

F(i) = ith feature

Ti = time it takes to program ith feature

For i = 0 to m,

M(i) = ith programmer

P(i) = ith programmer's preferred features

C(i) = $/hr the ith programmer will charge for working on features he doesn't like

h(i) = The number of hours the ith program is willing to work
We need to come up with a linear programming formulation that'll

1. finish all the features or find out if it's impossible
2. Minimize the cost

The linear programming problems I have done so far are usually the farmer wants to plant 2 crops kind of things. So this is really new and hard for me.
My approach was to have a set of inequalities for each programmer but the main problem here is that for some features they don't charge and some they do. Im not sure how to incorporate that into the formulation correctly. Also, a point to keep in mind is that a programmer can work on a feature for an hour and leave it and let another programmer take over

Comment: In the programming world, you are making an algorithm about threading and time management.  I would google searches on how to optimize threading for variables.  Ex:  thread 1 might be best at computing graphics because of the GPUs it has access to whereas thread 2 might have a LOT of ram, allowing for it to store large sets, etc.  These 2 threads would weight the accordingly tasks heavier and only pick up others where there are no heavy tasks left it likes to compute

Comment: The variables you need are x(i, j), how much programmer i works on feature j.

Comment: Ok, can you explain it a bit more because I havent seen a variable declared like that.
I guess the constraints would be 
x < h(i) 
x >= 0 
And Sum of all x's >= sum of all Ti
But I still feel like i'm missing how to optimally assign each programmer to his feature

Comment: Since "a programmer can work on a feature for an hour and leave it and let another programmer take over", it's not really an assignment that you're looking for, in the usual sense of the word. The next step is to figure out a workable objective.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation, which uses `i` to index both features and programmers, is a bit confusing, so I'll alter it for clarity. I'll use `i` to index features and `j` to index programmers.

We have `n` programmers and `m` features. Let `t(i,j)` be the amount of time the `j`th programmer spends working on the `i`th feature. These `t` variables are the decision variables we wish to solve for.

The `j`th programmer can only work a total of `h(j)` hours on all features, so we have that

```
 sum_{i=1}^m t(i,j) <= h(j) for all programmers j in 1,...,n
```

In order to complete the `i`th feature, the total hours worked by all programmers on  that feature must exceed the time `T(i)` required to implement that feature. So we have that

```
 sum_{j=1}^n t(i,j) >= T(i) for all features i
```

Let `P(i)`, which is a subset of `{1, ..., m}`, be the preference set of the `i`th progammer. Programmer's only charge for working on features that aren't in their preference set. So the cost of the `j`th programmer is given by

```
 sum_{i not in P(i)} C(j)*t(i,j)
```

Putting this all together, we have the following linear program

```
 minimize sum_{j=1}^n sum_{i not in  P} C(j)*t(i,j)
    t
 subject to  

          sum_{i=1}^m t(i,j) <= h(j), for all programmers j=1,...,n
          sum_{j=1}^n t(i,j) >= T(i), for all features    i=1,...,m
          0 <= t(i,j)                 for all i=1,...,m, j=1,...,n
```